# node-postgres: how to execute "WHERE col IN (<dynamic value list>)" query?

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I'm trying to execute a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

The problem is that the list of ids I want to filter against is not constant and needs to be different at every execution. I would also need to escape the ids, because they might come from untrusted sources, though I would actually escape anything that goes in a query regardless of the trustworthiness of the source.

node-postgres appears to work exclusively with bound parameters: `client.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $1', [ id ])`; this will work if I had a known number of values (`client.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($1, $2, $3)', [ id1, id2, id3 ])`), but will not work with an array directly: `client.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($1)', [ arrayOfIds ])`, as there does not seem to be any special handling of array parameters.

Building the query template dynamically according to the number of items in the array and expanding the ids array into the query parameters array (which in my actual case also contains other parameters besides the list of ids) seems unreasonably burdensome. Hard-coding the list of ids in the query template seems not viable either, as node-postgres does not provide any value escaping methods.

This seems like a very common use-case, so my guess is that I'm actually overlooking something, and not that it is not possible to use the common `IN (values)` SQL operator with node-postgres.

If anybody has solved this problem in a more elegant manner than those I listed above, or if I'm really missing something about node-postgres, please help.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but it appears that you want to pass a nested array as the first (and in this case, only) element of your substitutions array, since it expects each element in that paramater to be a substitution value.  Example: client.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($1)', [[arrayOfIds]]);

Comment: No, does not work that way (predictably). Apparently it tries to represent the array [1, 2, 3] as the string value "1,2,3", and the server returns an error "invalid input syntax for integer".

Comment: Can you post the full query it tries to execute when passing the array this way? I'm not as familiar with Posgres as MySQL but isn't that how you represent that query? IN (1,2,3) looks correct to me. Unless I totally misunderstood what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't see any way to capture the full query, as the actual network protocol message passes the query template and the list of parameters separately to the postgres server, and any final composition takes place on the server side. Even in the postgres log, there is no full query:


`2012-05-26 20:31:08 EEST ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1,3"
2012-05-26 20:31:08 EEST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ($1)`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

We've seen this question before on the github issues list.  The correct way is to dynamically generate your list of parameters based on the array.  Something like this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, "hello"];
var params = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  params.push('$' + i);
}
var queryText = 'SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE something IN (' + params.join(',') + ')';
client.query(queryText, arr, function(err, cb) {
 ...
});
```

That way you get the postgres parameterized escaping.

Comment: Since we are in Node.js, you are safe to use native map(). That simplifies code even more:

    params = arr.map(function(item, idx) {return '$' + idx});

Comment: Was about to scream bloody murder at putting plaintext into a query! Turns out it's just dollar symbols and numbers -_-'....

Comment: @srigi suggestion has a bug. It should be:
var params = arr.map(function(item, idx) {return '$' + (idx+1);});

Comment: This example will break, if any text element in the array contains single-quote symbols '.

Comment: @Heptic, even better would be to use const params!

Comment: An update to this answer is now in the node-postgres FAQ. The following works: `client.query("SELECT * FROM stooges WHERE name = ANY ($1)", [ ['larry', 'curly', 'moe'] ], ...);` See here: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ#11-how-do-i-build-a-where-foo-in--query-to-find-rows-matching-an-array-of-values

Comment: This is prone to SQL Injections.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRana I don't see how this is vulnerable to SQL injection. The query string being built is guaranteed to be of the form `SELECT id ... IN ($1, $2, ... $N)` which admits no possibility of injection -- it's just a `$`-parameterized query ready to be populated. (We never add actual query values to the string!) Then population of actual value occurs via the library, which is by nature immune to SQL injection (unless there's a serious bug in the library).

Comment: As @srigi noted, the map function is cool, but it does default to zero based index; so be sure to adjust the index because pg needs 1 based index.

Comment: This solution may be better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29575963/3070547. Guys should use the latest convention.

Answer (score 150):

It looks like you may have been close based on your comment to @ebohlman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771206/112196). You can use `WHERE id = ANY($1::int[])`. PostgreSQL will [convert](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) the array  to the type the parameter is cast to in `$1::int[]`. So here's a contrived example that works for me:

```
var ids = [1,3,4]; 

var q = client.query('SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE Id = ANY($1::int[])',[ids]);

q.on('row', function(row) {
  console.log(row);
})

// outputs: { id: 1 }
//          { id: 3 }
//          { id: 4 }
```

Comment: This lacks any quoting of the values in `arr`, and `node-postgres` does not provide any quoting methods. I'm looking for the "proper" way to approach this issue, so I'm disinclined to implement my own SQL literal quoting code. Besides, if I proceed in that direction, I would rather embed the list of ids directly in the query template, instead of preparing an array literal only to have it parsed again on the server-side.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "this lacks any quoting of the values in `arr`" please?

Comment: It means that if `arr` does not contain integers but, say, strings that include commas or braces, your code would fail or will perform incorrectly.

Comment: Of course it would, this is just an example. Surely you would sanitize the `IN` clause parameters prior to preparing the statement regardless of implementation. May be I've misunderstood the grounds of your question.

Comment: My question regards exactly the sanitization of the `IN` parameters. I cannot use bound parameters (since I don't know beforehand how many of them are there) and I cannot use value-quoting methods (since `node-postgres` does not offer any). Since it appears to me that the humble `IN` operator manages to defeat the whole purpose of bound parameters, I'm looking for a clean and canonical solution to this problem.

Comment: "Surely you would sanitize the IN clause parameters prior to preparing the statement regardless of implementation".
No.  That's one of the most important reasons to use parameter binding in the first place.  This answer gives people a security risk.

Comment: So given this answer is using a parameterized query and therefore the parameters are being parsed and escaped on the postgres server, where is the security risk? If there is one then there are bigger problems.

Comment: This seems like the cleanest answer, but executing the exact same query, I get the very generic: [Error: Connection terminated].  I don't see anything showing up in the postgres logmessages

Comment: @cecemel, it won't even work with an array of strings.

Answer (score 43):

The best solution I've found has been to use the `ANY` function with Postgres' array coercion. This lets you match a column with an arbitrary array of values as if you had written out `col IN (v1, v2, v3)`. This is the approach in [pero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829760/454967) but here I show that the performance of `ANY` is the same as `IN`.

#### Query

Your query should look like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ANY($1::int[])
```

That bit at the end that says `$1::int[]` can be changed to match the type of your "id" column. For example, if the type of your IDs is `uuid`, you'd write `$1::uuid[]` to coerce the argument to an array of UUIDs. [See here for the list of Postgres datatypes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/datatype.html).

This is simpler than writing code to construct a query string and is safe against SQL injections.

#### Example

With node-postgres, a complete JavaScript example looks like:

```
var pg = require('pg');

var client = new pg.Client('postgres://username:password@localhost/database');
client.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  var ids = [23, 65, 73, 99, 102];
  client.query(
    'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ANY($1::int[])',
    [ids],  // array of query arguments
    function(err, result) {
      console.log(result.rows);
    }
  );
});
```

#### Performance

One of the best ways to understand the performance of a SQL query is to look at how the database processes it. The sample table has about 400 rows and a primary key called "id" of type `text`.

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tests WHERE id = ANY('{"test-a", "test-b"}');
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tests WHERE id IN ('test-a', 'test-b');
```

In both cases, Postgres reported the same query plan:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on tests  (cost=8.56..14.03 rows=2 width=79)
  Recheck Cond: (id = ANY ('{test-a,test-b}'::text[]))
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tests_pkey  (cost=0.00..8.56 rows=2 width=0)
        Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{test-a,test-b}'::text[]))
```

You might see a different query plan depending on the size of your table, where there's an index, and your query. But for queries like the ones above, `ANY` and `IN` are processed the same way.

Comment: Note that while this is true for the form of ANY taking a set, there is a second form for each IN () and = ANY() and those are not completely equivalent. Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688

Answer (score 22):

Using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), this works well via the [CSV Filter](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#csv-filter) (comma-separated values):

```
const values = [1, 2, 3, 4];

db.any('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($1:csv)', [values])
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

And to address the concern about various data types, `:csv` modifier serializes the array into csv, while converting all values into their proper PostgreSQL format, according to their JavaScript type, even supporting the [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting).

And if you have mixed-type values like this: `const values = [1, 'two', null, true]`, you still will get the correctly escaped SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 'two', null, true)
```

**UPDATE**

From v7.5.1, [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) started supporting `:list` as an interchangeable alias for the `:csv` filter:

```
db.any('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($1:list)', [values])
```

Comment: Love this library

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use the `UNNEST` function like this:

```
 var ids = [23, 65, 73, 99, 102];
 var strs = ['bar', 'tar', 'far']
 client.query(
   'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(SELECT(UNNEST($1))',
    [ids],  // array of query arguments
    function(err, result) {
       console.log(result.rows);
    }
);
client.query(
   'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(SELECT(UNNEST($1))',
    [strs],  // array of query arguments
    function(err, result) {
       console.log(result.rows);
    }
);
```

I've used this in a stored procedure and it works fine. Believe it should work also from node-pg code.

You can read about the UNNEST function [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html).

Comment: This seems like a huge overkill, compared to the `id = ANY($1)` solutions

Answer (score 0):

Another posible solution is for example for REST API in NODE JS:

```
var name = req.body;//Body is a objetc that has properties for example provinces
var databaseRB = "DATABASENAME"
var conStringRB = "postgres://"+username+":"+password+"@"+host+"/"+databaseRB; 

var filter_query = "SELECT row_to_json(fc) FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type, ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geom)::json As geometry, row_to_json((parameters) As properties FROM radiobases As lg WHERE lg.parameter= ANY($1) )As f) As fc";

var client = new pg.Client(conStringRB);
client.connect();
var query = client.query(new Query(filter_query,[name.provinces]));
query.on("row", function (row, result) {
  result.addRow(row);
});
query.on("end", function (result) {
 var data = result.rows[0].row_to_json
   res.json({
     title: "Express API",
     jsonData: data
     });
});
```

Keep in mind that any type of array can be used

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and worked without casting to int[ ]. **using node-postgres with major version 8**

```
var q = client.query('SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE Id = ANY($1)',[ids]);
```

Answer (score -3):

The idea generally:

```
var invals = [1,2,3,4], cols = [...fields];
var setvs = vs => vs.map(v=> '$'+ (values.push(v))  ).join();

var values = [];
var text = 'SELECT '+ setvs(cols) +' FROM table WHERE id IN (' + setvs(invals) +')';
```