# Pass array from node-postgres to plpgsql function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql, node-postgres

The plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testarray (int[]) returns int as $$
  DECLARE
    len int;
  BEGIN
    len := array_upper($1);
  return len;
  END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The node-postgres query + test array:

```
var ta = [1,2,3,4,5];
client.query('SELECT testarray($1)', [ta], function(err, result) {
  console.log('err: ' + err);
  console.log('result: ' + result);
});
```

Output from node server:

> err: error: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
>   result: undefined

I also tried cast the parameter in the client query like `testarray($1::int[])` which returned the same error.

I changed the function argument to `(anyarray int)` and the output error changed:

> err: error: invalid input syntax for integer: "1,2,3,4,5"
>   result: undefined

As well as a couple other variations.

I seek the variation that produces no error and returns 5.

I read about the [Postgres parse-array issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/10) and this stackoverflow question on parameterised arrays in node-postgres:

- [node-postgres: how to execute "WHERE col IN (<dynamic value list>)" query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720420/node-postgres-how-to-execute-where-col-in-dynamic-value-list-query)

But the answer didn't seem to be there.

Answer (score 4):

The parameter has to be in one of these forms:

```
'{1,2,3,4,5}'         -- array literal
'{1,2,3,4,5}'::int[]  -- array literal with explicit cast
ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]      -- array constructor
```

Also, you can simplify your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testarray (int[])
  RETURNS int AS
$func$
BEGIN
  RETURN array_length($1, 1);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Or a simple SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testarray2 (int[])
  RETURNS int AS 'SELECT array_length($1, 1)' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Or just use [`array_length($1, 1)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) directly.

- `array_upper()` is the *wrong* function. Arrays can have arbitrary subscripts. **`array_length()`** does what you are looking for. Related question:

  - [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1)
- Both `array_length()` and `array_upper()` require *two* parameters. The second is the array dimension - `1` in your case.

Comment: thanks for the rundown on the arrays. I'd been going around in circles in the docs. I managed to get all of those variations working in node-postgres unparameterized. thanks for the detail on array_length.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the responses from PinnyM and Erwin. I reviewed the options and reread related answers.

the array formats described by Erwin work in node-postgres literally as follows:

```
'select testarray(' + "'{1,2,3,4,5}'" + ')'
'select testarray(' + "'{1,2,3,4,5}'" + '::INT[])'
'select testarray(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5])'
```

the tl:dr of [javascript quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244842)

to parameterize them in node-postgres:
(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829760/1526366))

```
var ta = [1,2,3,4,5];
var tas = '{' + ta.join() + '}';

...skipped over the pg connect code

client.query("select testarray($1)", [tas] ...
client.query("select testarray($1::int[])", [tas] ...
not sure about the ARRAY constructor.
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on the answer you posted, this might work for you:

```
var ta = [1,2,3,4,5];
var params = [];
for(var i = 1, i <= ta.length; i++) {
    params.push('$'+i);
}
var ta = [1,2,3,4,5];
client.query('SELECT testarray(\'{' + params.join(', ') + '}\')', ta, function(err, result) {
  console.log('err: ' + err);
  console.log('result: ' + result);
});
```

Comment: It produces a new error from postgresql: syntax error at or near "{"

Comment: Right, I forgot it needs to be enclosed by quotes. Updated.

Comment: that didn't work either. what did work is: client.query("select testarray($1::int[])", [ta], ...etc

Comment: This poses an extreme security risk!

Comment: @MilesRout can you clarify?  The joined params are server generated - is the problem the length of the passed params Array?