# PostgreSQL: Issue with passing array to procedure

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a type as:

```
CREATE TYPE status_record AS
   (
   id bigint,
   status boolean
   );
```

A procedure that does some processing with an array of type as input parameter as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_status(status_list status_record[])
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE  

BEGIN    
--does some processing
return 'SUCCESS'; 

end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Finally I queried the procedure as:

```
select *
from update_status(cast(ARRAY[(385,false),(387,false)] as status_record[]));
```

Everything works fine in pgadmin. Later when I tried to call the same using **Hibernate native SQL Query Ka Boom!!!** The following is displayed:

> ```
>  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>  ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
> ```

Final question: both `ARRAY[--something]` and `{--something}` does the same job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an **array literal** (text representation of the array), since the array constructor `ARRAY[...]` has to be evaluated by Postgres:

```
SELECT update_status('{"(1,t)","(2,f)"}'::status_record[]);
```

Maybe even without the explicit cast:

```
SELECT update_status('{"(1,t)","(2,f)"}');
```

There were similar cases on SO before:

- [Pass array from node-postgres to plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328016/pass-array-from-node-postgres-to-plpgsql-function/13328075#13328075)
- [How to pass custom type array to Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009822/how-to-pass-custom-type-array-to-postgres-function/17840058#17840058)

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the array and type initialization into a string, maybe you can then get around the problems with the obfuscation layer (aka ORM):

```
select update_status(cast('{"(1,true)", "(2,false)"}' as status_record[]));
```

I don't know Hibernate, so I can't tell if that will work.

Comment: But Hibernate fails to interpret ::status_record. will cast() operator work out?