# Cannot INSERT: ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, types, sql-insert

```sql
INSERT INTO user_data.user_data (username,randomint)
VALUES ('mahman',1);
```

> ```
> ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
> LINE 1: ... user_data.user_data (username,randomint) VALUES ('mahman...
> ```

```sql
INSERT INTO user_data.user_data (username,randomint)
VALUES {'mahman',1};
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
> LINE 1: ...O user_data.user_data (username,randomint) VALUES {'mahman',...
> ```

```sql
INSERT INTO user_data.user_data (username,randomint)
VALUES (2,{'mahman',1});
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
> LINE 1: ...ser_data.user_data (username,randomint) VALUES (2,{'mahman',...
> ```

The above varying `INSERT` statements fail in PostgreSQL. What is it that I am doing wrong?

My schema:

```
journeypost=# \dt user_data.*
           List of relations
  Schema   |   Name    | Type  | Owner 
-----------+-----------+-------+-------
 user_data | user_data | table | user
```

My table:

```
journeypost=# \d user_data.user_data
           Table "user_data.user_data"
  Column   |          Type           | Modifiers 
-----------+-------------------------+-----------
 username  | character varying(50)[] | not null
 randomint | integer                 | 
Indexes:
    "UsernameUnique" PRIMARY KEY, btree (username)
```

Comment: shall I keep the question? It does seem pretty silly now that I've seen it.

Comment: You are not the first to miss the significance of the trailing `[]` characters, so it might be useful to others.

Comment: I've just been caught by this, fairly new Postgres, this is really useful. Thanks.

Comment: @NoobDoob I'm glad you kept it!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your column `username` seems to be an ***array*** type, so the literal `'mahman'` is not valid input for it.

It would have to be **`'{mahman}'`**:

```
INSERT INTO user_data.user_data (username,randomint)
VALUES ('{mahman}',1);
```

(Or alter the data type to  plain `varchar` or `text` instead.)

Update confirms it: `character varying(50)[]`  is an *array* of `varchar(50)`.

About [array literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) / [array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

- [Pass array from node-postgres to plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328016/pass-array-from-node-postgres-to-plpgsql-function/13328075#13328075)
- [How to pass custom type array to Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009822/how-to-pass-custom-type-array-to-postgres-function/17840058#17840058)

Answer (score 0):

I called [generate_subscripts()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) with `ARRAY[a,b,c]` as shown below:

```sql
                         -- ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
SELECT generate_subscripts('ARRAY[a,b,c]'::VARCHAR[]);
```

Then, I got the same error below:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "ARRAY[a,b,c]"
LINE 1: SELECT generate_subscripts('ARRAY[a,b,c]'::VARCHAR[]);
                                   ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

So, I used `{a,b,c}` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
                         -- ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
SELECT generate_subscripts('{a,b,c}'::VARCHAR[], 1);
```