# PostgreSQL INSERT INTO return ERROR: column "***" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, string-constant

I want to insert a row `"India", "Aditya Birla Capital Ltd", "INE674K01013", "INR", "ADTB","Aditya Birla Capital"` to table `shares."shareNames"`. This is the postgresql code:

```
INSERT INTO shares."shareNames" ("country", "full_name", "isin_code", "currency", "symbol", "stock_name") 
VALUES ("India", "Aditya Birla Capital Ltd", "INE674K01013", "INR", "ADTB","Aditya Birla Capital")
RETURNING *;
```

> What I expected

I expected that `shares."shareNames"` would have a row like :

```
country|full_name               |isin_code   |currency|symbol|stock_name 
India  |Aditya Birla Capital Ltd|INE674K01013|INR     |ADTB  |Aditya Birla Capital
```

> Actual result

Instead:

```
ERROR:  column "India" does not exist
LINE 3: VALUES ("India", "Aditya Birla Capital Ltd",
                ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 125
```

Request: Please help me fix this problem!

Answer (score 4):

In PostgreSQL the double quoting used only for DB entities names like table, column names. For escape strings use single quotes like:

```
INSERT INTO shares."shareNames" (
    "country", "full_name", "isin_code", "currency", "symbol", "stock_name"
) VALUES (
   'India', 'Aditya Birla Capital Ltd', 'INE674K01013', 'INR', 'ADTB', 'Aditya Birla Capital'
)
RETURNING *;
```

Comment: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "Aditya Birla Capital Ltd"
LINE 4:    'India', 'Aditya Birla Capital Ltd', 'INE674K01013', 'INR...
                    ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 134

Comment: It is not working, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
INSERT INTO shares."shareNames" ("country", "full_name", "isin_code", "currency", "symbol", "stock_name") 
VALUES ('India', 'Aditya Birla Capital Ltd', 'INE674K01013', 'INR', 'ADTB','Aditya Birla Capital')
RETURNING *;
```

Comment: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "Aditya Birla Capital Ltd"
LINE 2: VALUES ('India', 'Aditya Birla Capital Ltd', 'INE674K01013',...
                         ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 125

Comment: check this post;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519063/cannot-insert-error-array-value-must-start-with-or-dimension-information

Comment: It is not working

Comment: Ok i will check it

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help