# Match any letter in a string

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

Table `flights`:

| ID | Path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NZ:EU |
| 2 | JP:CA |

```
SELECT
    path
FROM
    flights
WHERE
    path ILIKE '%' || 'jpca' || '%'
```

Above query isn't working, it needs to return second row. But it works if I provide for example:

- jp
- ca
- p
- jp:ca
- CA

It should also work for:

- jpca
- pj
- cp
- a:p

Regex answer is also accepted.

Comment: Why would you expect `'jpca'` to match the string `'JP:CA'`?  If you want a match you need `'jp:ca'`

Comment: Do you mean `path ILIKE ANY '{%j%,%p%,%c%,%a%}'::text[]`? But tbh this doesn't make much sense

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can it be done through regex?

Comment: @Bergi ye this won't be helpful

Comment: @MusabShakeel So what exactly *are* you looking for then? `path ILIKE '%jp%ca'`?

Comment: @Bergi any letter/character matches in Path string, it needs to return that record. I provided example too. Postgres ILIKE is doing search linearly (left to right) on a string, but I need a solution which can search letter by letter or something like that. So if I provide "pj" it needs to return "JP:CA" record, if I provide jpca it needs to return "JP:CA" record and so on.

Comment: @MusabShakeel So you mean *all* of the letters of the string you provide must be found in the `offset` column value? But in arbitrary order?

Comment: @Bergi I didn't properly understand your question, but if I provide `ac`, it matches second record and returns `JP:CA` but if I provide some odd string like `f`, `PH` etc. these aren't available in any plot so it'll just return no record (null).

Comment: @MusabShakeel Yes, that answers the question. So if you provided `':'`, it would match both rows?

Comment: @Bergi yes it'll return both rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care for the characters of your term to occur in exactly that sequence, but only want to specify a search that matches each of these characters somewhere, you can use the [`ALL` keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.17) to match multiple `ILIKE` patterns at once:

```
SELECT path
FROM flights
WHERE path ILIKE ALL( ARRAY['%j%', '%p%', '%c%', '%a%'] );
```

Now to generate that array from just a single string, you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM flights
WHERE path ILIKE ALL (SELECT '%' || regexp_split_to_table('jpca', '') || '%');
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bd2ae4e046b7b8840bdc3925cc2ae536))</sup>

Comment: It's looking pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier if you process the column `path` before the match

#### Match individual characters

(Updated question.)

Assumptions:

- All characters are significant, including punctuation.
- A pattern matches if every character is found in the `path`.
- Match case-insensitive.

Lower-case both operands and treat them as **arrays**.
If there can be duplicate letters, eliminate them for efficiency.

```sql
SELECT path
FROM   flights
WHERE  string_to_array(lower(path), null)
    @> string_to_array(lower('JPCA'), null);
```

Or:

```sql
...
WHERE  string_to_array(lower(path), null)  @> '{j,p,c,a}';
```

Returns all rows where path contains every character in the search patter.

[**`@>`** is the array "contains" operator.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)

If the table is big, support it with an **GIN index** on the expression to make that fast (which is the point of this route):

```
CREATE INDEX flights_path_array_lower_gin_idx ON flights
USING gin (string_to_array(lower(path), null));
```

Related, with links to more:

- [GIN index on array column not used, even after setting `enable_seqscan` to off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71992917/gin-index-on-array-column-not-used-even-after-setting-enable-seqscan-to-off/71993467#71993467)

**If** you don't need index support, a simper check will do:

```
...
WHERE path ~* ALL (string_to_array('JPCA', null))
```

**`~*`** is the case-insensitive regular expression match operator.

Related:

- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)
- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)
- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

#### Substring matching

(Original question.)

Assumptions:

- The sequence of characters in the search term must be matched.
- Only ASCII letters are significant
- Duplicate characters are significant

```sql
SELECT path
FROM   flights
WHERE  lower(regexp_replace(path, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g')) ~ lower('JPCA');
```

This removes all characters except A-Z and a-z and casts the result to lower case before trying a regular expression match. Related:

- [Extract numbers from a field in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564475/extract-numbers-from-a-field-in-postgresql/40564710#40564710)
- [LOWER LIKE vs iLIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336665/lower-like-vs-ilike/20337500#20337500)

If your table is big and you need it to be fast, create a trigram  [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html):

```
CREATE INDEX flights_path_expr_idx ON flights
USING gin (lower(regexp_replace(path, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g') gin_trgm_ops);
```

Requires the additional module [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) installed. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

**Or** add a "generated column" to your table and a plain B-tree index on that:

```
ALTER TABLE flights 
  ADD COLUMN path_ascii text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (lower(regexp_replace(path, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g'))) STORED;

CREATE INDEX flights_path_ascii_trgm_idx ON flights USING gin (path_ascii gin_trgm_ops);
```

Then:

```
SELECT path FROM flights WHERE path_ascii ~ 'jpca';
```

See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Comment: will it work if `pj`, `jp:ca` or `cp` is provided?

Comment: @MusabShakeel: No. All your examples suggest that the sequence of characters must match.

Comment: sorry about that, btw I recently clear it in my question's comment and updated the question as well, do you have a solution that can solve nonsequential and symbol problem?

Comment: @MusabShakeel: I added another solution for your changed question.