# plpgsql function with text array parameter coming from node postgres

Tags: arrays, node.js, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following function in plpgsql

```
create or replace  function domix(mix int[],newmix text[]) RETURNS integer AS \$$
DECLARE
  I INT;
  newmix_char text;
BEGIN
  FOREACH newmix_char IN ARRAY newmix
    LOOP
     insert into mix_table (name) values (newmix_char);
    END LOOP;
  FOREACH I IN ARRAY MIX
    LOOP
      insert into domix_table (id) values (I);
   END LOOP;
  RETURN 1;
 END;
 \$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The server is a nodes server.
I have seen [Pass array from node-postgres to plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328016/pass-array-from-node-postgres-to-plpgsql-function)  and I have followed it.
I pass the values as indicated,(domixids is an array of int, newmixes is an array of strings)

```
 'mix': '{'+domixids.join() +'}',
 'newmix':'{'+ newmixes.join()+'}',
```

printing on the server before the db call shows: mixids {14,13} newmix {si,non}

The function behaves as I expected for the mixids - loops and inserts a row for each id. But the newmix is considered as 1 string and gets inserted as such, no looping.
I have tried with {'si','non'} but with same result. 
Where is my error ? I am obviously not sending the function what it is expecting. Or I am completely out and this is not the way to loop through and array of strings ? I am using Postgres 9.4
Thanks for any pointer

I am adding more details ( tried the suggestions - badly since it did not work). As I said all works well for the integers, and I obviously am not passing correctly the string arrays. I get the list as a set of strings comma separated from the interface (newmix).I split

```
   var newmixes = newmix.split(/,/);
   console.log(new mixes);  --> ["yes", "non", "trois"]
   var infoWhat= { 'mix': '{'+domixids.join() +'}',
            'newmix':'{'+ newmixes.join()+'}'
               };
   console.log(infoWhat);   ----> Object {mix: "{}",new mix: "{yes,no}"}}
```

In the database I get : {yes,no} in that field.
I tried passing "{''yes'',''no''}", same result I get {''yes'',''no''}.

My function is called using node-postgres as a prepared statement:
     "select domix($1,$2);"
and $1,$2 are passed by req.body.mix, req.body.domix

If I have to explicitly cast as  ::TEXT[]  where should I do it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried explicit cast `'{''si'',''non''}'::text[]` or array constructor `ARRAY['si', 'non']` following the answer of question  you have mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328016/pass-array-from-node-postgres-to-plpgsql-function

Comment: How do you pass the values into the function? For the strings it must be `ARRAY['si','non']`.

Comment: thanks, I added information in my question. I will try to do the cast

Comment: Don't put "solved" in your question. Just accept your answer, and the question will be marked as "solved"

Comment: ok - will do that tomorrow, it does not allow me to do it today. I did not know how to do it, now I learned, thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put the explicit cast in the function call:

```
select function($1,$2::TEXT[]);
```

and now the data is entered correctly.
Thanks for the help and pointers that helped me find the solution!