Use jsonb array in where clause
I have this table:
Directives Table:
user_id: 5
account_id: 1
filters: { "a": "my value", "names": ["myname", "yourname", "theirname"] } -- jsonb

I want to filter the rows from the Directives table by saying if filters->name is IN a set (array?) of elements:
ie:
SELECT * FROM directives
WHERE filters->names IN ['yourname', 'theirname']


What you show as pseudo-code would work like this with the jsonb ? operator:
SELECT *
FROM   directives
WHERE  filters->'names' ? 'yourname';

If you are actually looking for any intersection between the nested JSON array and an input array, use the jsonb ?| operator:
SELECT *
FROM   directives
WHERE  filters->'names' ?| '{noname, yourname, hisname}';

fiddle
Notably, the filter-input for the latter is a Postgres array, not a JSON array.
Either can be supported with a GIN index on the expression filters->'names'. See:

Index for finding an element in a JSON array


Hi, how may I use an Array here '{noname, yourname, hisname}'? Thanks

I tested your suggestion and it works really well, thank you Erwin!

I ended up using filters->'names' ?| array['noname', 'yourname', 'hisname'].

@RafaelMora: About array literal and array constructor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328075/939860

Oh I get it so it is the same thing, thanks! @ErwinBrandstetter
