# PostgreSQL list parameter in Go (using database/SQL and pq)

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, prepared-statement

I'm trying to write a query that takes a list parameter (ie, a single parameter which is a list of values). It appears that this is at least sometimes possible in PostgreSQL (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829760/836390). What I want is something like this:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in $1", []int{1, 2, 3})
```

However, when I execute this using the [pq](https://github.com/lib/pq) driver, I get an error:

```
sql: converting Exec argument #0's type: unsupported type []int, a slice
```

Is this simply not supported in `pq` yet, or is this not supported in `database/sql`, or not in PostgreSQL at all, or what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [pq.Array](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/array.go) with slice parameters nowadays. So the query would look like:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in $1", pq.Array([]int{1, 2, 3}))
```

Answer (score 6):

So it looks like [pq](http://github.com/lib/pq) uses [database/sql](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql)'s default ValueConverter, which has no ability to handle slices (see the [documentation](http://golang.org//pkg/database/sql/driver/#pkg-variables) for DefaultParameterConverter).

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to work due to a syntax error. I modified the answer a bit and got it to work for me.

The resource I used was the [pq.Array](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Array) function documentation.

```golang
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ANY($1)", pq.Array([]int{1, 2, 3}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at using an alternative Postgres client: https://github.com/vmihailenco/pg

The readme details array support and includes an example of using a slice.

```
    _, err := db.Query(users,
    `WITH users (name, emails) AS (VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?))
    SELECT * FROM users`,
    "admin", []string{"admin1@admin", "admin2@admin"},
    "root", []string{"root1@root", "root2@root"},
)
```

(I've not used this myself, but a look over it shows promise).

Answer (score 0):

This does in fact appear to be 'temperamental'. Here are two I would attempt:

`rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in ($1)", []int{1, 2, 3})`

or

`rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ANY($1::[]int)", []int{1, 2, 3})`

Comment: Sorry, neither of those work. My suspicion is that the "unsupported type" error is coming from the Go side, prior to processing the query string itself (In Postgres, query parameters are processed by the Postgres server, which means that the client never constructs a query from parameters, but simply sends the query raw and sends the parameters separately). If it was coming from the server, the error wouldn't have used the Go syntax and terminology, "[]int" and "slice."

Comment: Can you get the exact string that is being executed on the server ('mogrify' it?)

Comment: It's never making it to the server.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. See my answer.