# PostGis query returns invalid geometry error when performed with Go

Tags: go, postgis

I tried to select the `id` from the `steps` table having their location within 1km from (x,y) some PostGis with Go using the pgx library.

I've tested the following code which returns an error: `parse error - invalid geometry (SQLSTATE XX000)`

```golang
func search(lat float32, lng float32) return (string, error){
    searchQuery   = "SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT($1 $2)'::geography, location) < 1000"

    // GetSession returns *pgxpool.Pool
    rows, err := postgres.GetSession().Query(context.Background(), searchQuery,
    lat,
    lng)
    if err != nil {
        // ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry (SQLSTATE XX000)
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    ...
}
```

Then, I've just changed the query using [ST_SetSRID](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) & [ST_MakePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)

```golang
searchQuery   = "SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($1, $2), 4326)::geography, location) < 1000"
```

... but ...

### 1) I still don't know why my fist version of the query

`"SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT($1 $2)'::geography, location) < 1000"`

returns a geometry error whereas it's working when I test it straight into *pgadmin* replacing $1 and $2 with random coordinate values like

`"SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT(0.44 3.40)'::geography, location) < 1000"`

### 2) I'm not sure if using [ST_Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) with ST_SetSRID and ST_MakePoint is the most efficient way to check that a point is close to another one.

Comment: Can you try `ST_GeomFromText` instead? In regards to your 2nd question, you can read this http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2021/05/indexes-and-queries.html -  you should most likely be using st_dwithin and utilise a spatial index which you can build with your location values with `geography`, he explains that in the tail auf the post.

Comment: It's also working in pgadmin but Go returns `ERROR: syntax error at or near \"$2\" (SQLSTATE 42601)` for the request `SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText(POINT($1 $2), 4326)::geography, location) < 1000`. The common thing between the 2 rejected request id the presence of the surrounding quotes ...

Comment: Yes, it is expecting a string. Add quotes before, so 'POINT(...)'

Comment: sorry I mistyped the request it already has quotes indeed: `SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT($1 $2)', 4326)::geography, location) < 1000` and the presence of quotes is the common denominator in the 2 rejected requests but don't know why ...

Comment: Can you print the statement after the arguments have been inserted?

Comment: There's no option to print the request generated by the SQL driver, I can only simulate it performing a string replacement. So it gives me this: `SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0.440000 3.400000)', 4326), location) < 1000` and it works as expected in pgadmin but still not using the Go Query func :/

Comment: I am not familiar with Go but this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928212/postgres-list-parameter-in-go-using-database-sql-and-pq - I do not think this is a PostGIS specific issue, it is how you are formatting the strings with your params lat and lon

Comment: `'SRID=4326;POINT($1 $2)'` is a string literal, postgres' ordinal parameter placeholders should NOT be in string literals. This is not a problem of Go. This is how postgres treats string literals. i.e. `'$1'` != `$1`, one is a plain string, the other a parameter placeholder that *postgres* (not Go) will replace with data sent by the client to the server.

Comment: ... if you want to combine string literals with parameter placeholders, use string concatenation, e.g. something like this: `'SRID=4326;POINT(' || $1::text || ' ' || $2::text || ')'`.

Comment: On a side note, you are passing attributes with `lat` first, then `long`, but points in Postgis must be expressed as longitude first, then latitude.

Comment: JFI using postgres string concat gives me a weird error ... `"SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT(' || $1::text || ' ' || $2::text || ')', location) < 1000"` `function st_distance(text, geometry) is not unique (SQLSTATE 42725)`

Comment: @Big_Boulard it means that there's no `st_distance` function with the signature `(text, geometry)`, that means that you probably need to add **explicit** cast to the `text` argument to a type that `st_distance` can accept.

Comment: @Big_Boulard you can see here that there are two st_distances https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html... the one you want has the signature `(geometry, geometry)`, so just modify your query like so: `ST_Distance(('SRID=4326;POINT(' || $1::text || ' ' || $2::text || ')')::geometry, location)` -- note how the string literal with its concatenations is wrapped in extra parentheses, this is just to enforce the right order of evaluation, i.e. to enforce the cast `::geometry` is applied to the text *after* it is concatenated.

Comment: Thx @mkopriva it was a bit though for me on this one. So just for the record, here is the version using the recommended ST_DWithin (because it leverage a spatial index while ST_Distance doesn't): `SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_DWithin(('SRID=4326;POINT(' || 0.440000::text || ' ' || 3.400000::text || ')')::geometry, location, 1000);`

Comment: @Big_Boulard I hope you meant `$1` and `$2` instead of `0.440000` and `3.400000` because otherwise this whole comment section is pointless :).

Comment: @Big_Boulard feel free to answer your own question, it will help others, I think it's a common pitfall for all different kind of languages

Comment: @mkopriva yes I meant $1 and $2 sorry for that I will write the answer tomorrow you can count on me. Thank you all guys 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Query Issue

`SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT($1 $2)'::geography, location) < 1000`

note that $1 is lng and $2 should be lat

### Why is-it happening?

`'SRID=4326;POINT($1 $2)'` is a **string literal**, **postgres' ordinal parameter placeholders** should **NOT be in string literals**. This is not a problem of Go. This is how postgres treats string literals. i.e. `'$1' != $1`, one is a **plain string**, the other a **parameter placeholder that postgres (not Go) will replace with data sent by the client to the server**.

### Solution

.. if you want to combine string literals with parameter placeholders, use string concatenation:

```sql
ST_Distance(('SRID=4326;POINT(' || $1::text || ' ' || $2::text || ')')::geometry, location)
```

Note how the string literal with its concatenations is wrapped in extra parentheses, this is just to enforce the right order of evaluation, i.e. to enforce the cast `::geometry` applied to the text after it is concatenated.

### Optimization

You should most likely be using `st_dwithin` and utilise a **spatial index** which you can build with your location values with geography, he explains that in the tail of the post. See [blog.cleverelephant.ca/2021/05/indexes-and-queries.html](https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2021/05/indexes-and-queries.html)

#### Fixed SQL Query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_DWithin(('SRID=4326;POINT(' || $1::text || ' ' || $2::text || ')')::geometry, location, 1000);
```

#### Fixed Go function

```golang
func search(lat float32, lng float32) return (string, error){
    searchQuery   = "SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM steps WHERE ST_DWithin(('SRID=4326;POINT(' || $1::text || ' ' || $2::text || ')')::geometry, location, 1000);"

    // GetSession returns *pgxpool.Pool
    rows, err := postgres.GetSession().Query(context.Background(), searchQuery,
    lng,
    lat)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    ...
}
```