# pg-promise - Error operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am trying to run the query:

```
let query =
    `
        DELETE FROM
            ${table_name}
        WHERE
            _id IN ($1::bigint[])
            AND
            account_id = $2
    `
let fields =
    [
        _ids,
        account_id,
    ]
```

but it's giving me the error:

```
operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]
```

`_ids` is an array.

## NOTE

The error I was getting once implementing the answer was:

```
GraphQLError: Int cannot represent non-integer value: []
```

This was simply a GraphQL error, nothing to do with postgres.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `IN` operator expects either a [set of rows with exactly one column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN), or a [parenthesized list of scalar expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR).  It doesn't accept an array.

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29575963/50552) suggests `:list`, which tells pg-promise to do the right thing:

```
WHERE _id IN ($1:list)
```

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829760/50552) suggests `= any`, where `ANY` is a [Postgres operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) that does accept arrays:

```
WHERE _id = ANY ($1::int[])
```

Comment: for either example, I'm getting the error: `GraphQLError: Int cannot represent non-integer value: []` and shouldn't it be bigint? Since the `_id` is `bigserial`

Comment: this was actually the answer. The issue I was getting was GraphQL's error zzz.