# PostgreSQL + JS: Creating a query based on a random array length of 1-5 values

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, algorithm

I have a function that returns an Array of 1-5 integers, each time the array 
length is different:

[5, 10, 45, 55, 64]

How would I generate a SQL query based on the length of that array?

Example: if the array is 3 integers long I would need a query such as

Array: [10, 25, 30]

SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id IN($1, $2, $3)

if the array is 5 integers long I would need:

Array: [5, 9, 20, 41, 35]

SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id IN($1, $2, $3, &4, &5)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720420/node-postgres-how-to-execute-where-col-in-dynamic-value-list-query. basically just join the params with ',' for the in clause.

Comment: much thanks for the link, I couldn't figure out how to word my question so google would return the correct question answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build IN part in a variable and attach it to the SQL

If your array has [10, 25, 30]

build a variable with  `v = "$1, $2, $3"`

if the array has [5, 9, 20, 41, 35]

build the variable with `v = "$1, $2, $3, $4, $5"`

Then attach it to the SQL

```
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id IN(v)'
```