# Promise.all and .map returning null

Tags: node.js, postgresql, promise, array.prototype.map

```
const returnPostData = async (req, res, initialPostsQueryArray) => {
    const promises = initialPostsQueryArray.map((post) => {

        let postObject;

        voteCount = sumValues(post.voting_options);
        pool.query('SELECT voting_option FROM votes WHERE user_id = $1 AND post_id = $2', 
            [req.user.userId, post.post_id], 
            (error, results) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return res.json({'Error': error.detail});
                }
                userVoteOption = results.rows[0].voting_option;
        });
        postObject.voteCount = voteCount;
        postObject.userVoteOption = userVoteOption;
        return postObject;
    });

    return Promise.all(promises).then(postData => {
        return res.json(postData);
    })
}
```

I'm trying to return an array of the postObjects for each post. For some reason it keeps on printing null for these objects because the return res.json is somehow running before the promises are even done. Any help is appreciated.

I had this problem before and used the same code, but it didn't work for this one for some reason.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit and will discuss the new code in [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587575/multiple-queries-in-a-map-function)

Answer (score 2):

Multiple problems:

- You `return postObject` [before `userVoteOption` is assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)
- You don't actually [use promises with node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries/)
- …and therefore the return value of the `map` callback is not a promise
- You never initialse `postObject`
- You marked your function as `async` but never use `await`
- You handle each error in the loop individually (which leads to `res.json` being called multiple times in case of multiple errors)

To fix these, use

```
async function returnPostData(req, res, initialPostsQueryArray) {
    try {
        const promises = initialPostsQueryArray.map(async (post) => {
            const voteCount = sumValues(post.voting_options);
            const results = await pool.query(
                'SELECT voting_option FROM votes WHERE user_id = $1 AND post_id = $2', 
                [req.user.userId, post.post_id]
            );
            const userVoteOption = results.rows[0].voting_option;
            const postObject = { voteCount, userVoteOption };
            return postObject;
        });
        const postData = await Promise.all(promises);
        res.json(postData);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json({'Error': error.detail});
    }
}
```

In addition, you actually shouldn't use a loop at all here. Just query multiple rows from postgres at once! Using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829760/1048572) to supply the ids:

```
async function returnPostData(req, res, initialPostsQueryArray) {
    try {
        const voteCounts = new Map();
        const ids = [];
        for (const post of initialPostsQueryArray) {
            ids.push(post.post_id);
            voteCounts.set(post.post_id, sumValues(post.voting_options));
        }
        const {rows} = await pool.query(
            'SELECT post_id, voting_option FROM votes WHERE user_id = $1 AND post_id = ANY($2::int[])', 
            [req.user.userId, ids]
        );
        const postData = rows.map(row => {
            const postObject = {
                voteCount: voteCounts.get(row.post_id),
                userVoteOption: row.voting_option,
            };
            return postObject;
        });
        const postData = await Promise.all(promises);
        res.json(postData);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json({'Error': error.detail});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did some deleting and typing into stack so some things got messed up. My main goal was to figure out why null was printing out and i see how you did "const postData = await Promise.all(promises);
        res.json(postData);" but I'm still unable to get that working. I have a lot of nested queries in the function that I didn't post here. Could it have something to do with that?

Comment: Sure could have something to do with that… You might [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65585755/edit) to update small things from your actual code, but if it's a substantial difference you better might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: In general, don't do lot of nested queries. Use SQL joins for better performance.

Comment: I edited the code to be the entire function I currently have. Yes I'm a newbie at sql, my father told me the same thing. Moving from firestore to postgres so a little different lol. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You still haven't converted the `pool.query` calls to use promises instead of callbacks, so that you can `await` them in sequence.