# Array value Passing into SQL Server IN Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, typescript, sequelize.js

I am using Nodejs Typescript and SQL Server.
I wrote query to find array matching values from database. If I pass static array values then data is fetching. When add dynamic array values query is not executing.
My query is below.

```
SELECT Name,id,date FROM venue where name IN('Bangalore','Delhi')
```

below query is not executing

```
let input = ["Bangalore","Delhi"]
SELECT Name,id,date FROM venue where name IN('${input}')
```

What I observed is When I pass dynamic values into query its taking `""` quotes ie `"Bangalore","Delhi"` But query is expecting is single quotes `''`

I know In Nodejs we can pass `?` and values as parameter but in our case we using typescript and sequelize it has limitation. I unable to use that format.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `array#map` to create quoted city name which will be passed inside `IN` clause.

```js
const input = ["Bangalore","Delhi"],
      query = `SELECT Name,id,date FROM venue where name IN (${input.map(city => `'${city}'`)})`;
console.log(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the values inside `IN` clause is passing as an array. Please take a look at this [array value passing inside IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720420/node-postgres-how-to-execute-where-col-in-dynamic-value-list-query)