# How do I write postgres IN operator query in express js(node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nodes

How I wrote

```
var staff=[1,2,3];
await client.query(
    "SELECT user_id FROM group_user WHERE user_id IN($1)",
    staffs
);
```

Throws error that only one parameter need to be given

Comment: You can find some options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10720420) for node-postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
`SELECT user_id FROM group_user WHERE user_id in (${ids})`
```

Comment: This creates a vulnerability to injection attacks.