# How to add "x in y" clause in ExpressJS

Tags: sql, express

In Postgres I have created a simple table called `tags` with these columns:

- tag_id
- tag
- owner_id

In ExpressJS, this query works fine:

```
return pool.query(`SELECT tag_id, tag FROM tags WHERE owner_id = $1`, [ownerId]);
```

Now what I want to do is restrict which tags are returned via an array of tag values I'm passing in:

```
const tagsCsv = convertArrayToCSV(tags);  // Example: "'abc','def'"
return pool.query(`SELECT tag_id, tag FROM tags WHERE owner_id = $1 AND tag IN ($2)`, [ownerId, tagsCsv]);
```

The code doesn't crash but it returns an empty array when I know for a fact that both `abc` & `def` are sample tags in my table.

I thus suspect something is wrong with my syntax but am not sure what.  Might anyone have any ideas?

Robert

Comment: try `[ownerId, tags]` IN expects an array of items not a string

Comment: What database library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I did more searching and found this: [node-postgres: how to execute "WHERE col IN (<dynamic value list>)" query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720420/node-postgres-how-to-execute-where-col-in-dynamic-value-list-query)

Following the examples in there, I stopped converting the string array to a CSV string and instead did this:

```
const tags: Array<string> = values.tags;
return pool.query(`SELECT tag_id, tag FROM tags WHERE owner_id = $1 AND tag = ANY($2::text[])`, [ownerId, tags]);
```

This worked perfectly, returning the records I was expecting!